# Define Function with Many Variants

Tags: function-construction

I need to define many variants of a function which take special values when any of the arguments are zero (or the calculation can be significantly simplified).  I can imagine this can be done programmatically, but so far I have not found how.

For example, consider the following example:

```
f[0, 0] = 0;
f[x_, 0] = Integrate[foo[xx, 0], {xx, 0, x}];
f[0, y_] = Integrate[foo[0, yy], {yy, 0, y}];
f[x_, y_] = Integrate[foo[xx, yy], {xx, 0, x}, {yy, 0, y}];
```

This is already a little annoying to do with 2 arguments, but I need to do something similar with a 6-function arguments...

Any hint as to how this can be done?

---

Even better, I'm defining these functions within another function and thus I know which argument(s) will be zero at run time.  Thus I have currently something like:

```
process[f[n_, m_, a_, b_]] := Block[{disc},
  disc[0, 0] = 0;
  disc[x_, 0] = Sum[auxFunction[f[n, m, x, 0], v], {v, {x}}];
  disc[0, y_] = Sum[auxFunction[f[n, m, 0, y], v], {v, {y}}];
  disc[x_, y_] = Sum[auxFunction[f[n, m, x, y], v], {v, {x, y}}];

  disc[a, b] / (2 I)
];
```

It is clear that as the `Block` is being evaluated, I will know which of `a` and/or `b` will be `0` thus only one of the 4 variants needs to be computed.

Comment: How many times will you _run_ the code, vs. how many times will you _write_ the code? :p

Answer (score 3):

You may use [`Sequence`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sequence.html) and [`Nothing`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nothing.html) to build the [`Integrate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html) variable list with [Formal Symbols](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MathematicalAndOtherNotation.html#173509264) to prevent naming conflicts with variables outside of your function.

With

```
foo[x_, y_, z_] := x + 2 y + 3 z
```

then

```
f[x_, y_, z_] :=
  Integrate[
   foo[\[FormalX], \[FormalY], \[FormalZ]],
   Sequence @@ {
     If[x != 0, {\[FormalX], 0, x}, Nothing],
     If[y != 0, {\[FormalY], 0, y}, Nothing],
     If[z != 0, {\[FormalZ], 0, z}, Nothing]
     }
   ];
```

Which gives the desired results

```
{#, f @@ #} & /@
   Rest@Tuples[{0, 1}, 3] //
  Prepend[{"{x,y,z}", "f[x,y,z]"}] //
 Grid
```

> [image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Close, but your example doesn't quite give the right result.  There shouldn't be any dependence on the formal symbols in the output.  The other thing is that I want to use `Set` and not `SetDelayed` as the 0-cases can be precomputed more easily.

Comment: @JP-Ellis The formal symbols are easily replaced: `f[0, 1, 0] /. 
 Thread[{\[FormalX], \[FormalY], \[FormalZ]} -> {x, y, z}]` . They are needed in the function as "safe" variables to use for `Integrate`.

Comment: And what about using `Set` vs `SetDelayed`?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to do exactly what I want with some help from @Edmund's answer.

The full answer, using `Integrate` as the example is:

```
Off[RuleDelayed::rhs];
Do[
  With[{
      head = f @@ (vars /. x : (a | b | c) :> x_),
      opts = vars /. {
        x : (a | b | c) :> {x, 0, x},
        0 -> Nothing
      },
      replacement = Thread[Complement[{a, b, c}, vars] -> 0]
    },
    If[Length[opts] == 0,
      head = 0;
      ,
      head = Integrate[2 (a + b + c), Sequence @@ opts] /. replacement;
    ]
  ]
  ,
  {vars, Tuples[{{0, a}, {0, b}, {0, c}}]}
]
```

Checking the definitions of `f` once this has been evaluated gives:

```
f[0,  0,  0 ] = 0
f[0,  0,  c_] = c^2
f[0,  b_, 0 ] = b^2
f[0,  b_, c_] = b c (b+c)
f[a_, 0,  0 ] = a^2
f[a_, 0,  c_] = a c (a+c)
f[a_, b_, 0 ] = a b (a+b)
f[a_, b_, c_] = a b c (a+b+c)
```

as desired, with the right hand side begin evaluated already.

A breakdown of how this all works:

1. The `Do` loop goes through every combinations of the arguments being possibly non-zero as generated by `Tuples[{{0, a}, {0, b}, {0, c}}]`.
2. The `With` function generates the left-handed side of `Set`.  That is, `head` will be `f[a_, 0, b_]` for example.  This must be done by using `With` as `Set` holds the left hand side remains unevaluated which prevents placing `f @@ (...)` directly.

   1. `vars /. x : (a | b | c) :> x_` converts the variables with the corresponding pattern.  Note that since we have a pattern on the right hand side, Mathematica will highlight this as being wrong and will produce error messages (which are disabled by `Off[RuleDelayed::rhs]` but this is one of the few cases where we *do* want patterns on the right hand side of the replacement.
   2. The `opts` variable stores the integration variables and bounds which will be used by `Integrate`, replacement `0` with nothing.
   3. The `replacement` variable is used to replacement unintegrated variables by `0` (as they would in fact be integrated from `0` to `0`.
3. In the body of `With` we can now perform the definition of `f` with

   ```
   head = Integrate[2 (a + b + c), Sequence @@ opts] /. replacement;
   ```

   which is evaluated as if the right hand side was `f[a_, 0, b_]` (and similar).